# Flash Movie Doesn't Show in IE

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

I have a flash movie that runs fine in FF, Opera, Safari but not in IE. When I right click on the blank box that sits there now, I don't even get the usual flash menu that shows.

Could someone please look at [link text](http://rants-group.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the follwing:

1.

In

```
<PARAM NAME="wmode" VALUE="transparent>
```

add the missing quotes at the end of transparent:

```
<PARAM NAME="wmode" VALUE="transparent">
```

---

2.

In

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"
WIDTH="350" HEIGHT="309" id="flashslide" ALIGN="">
```

set width and height to 2000:

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"
WIDTH="2000" HEIGHT="2000" id="flashslide" ALIGN="">
```

Comment: That was it, thank you. Just another thing overlooked. Why can't IE just display broken code like the other nice browsers do, lol

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Further explanation:

In your code, you are using two different methods to embed the flash movie:

1. via `<object ...>...</object>`
2. via `<embed ...>...</embed>`

This bears the danger that when you change an important setting, you only change it in one variant, but forget the other.

In the presence of both variants available, the browser has to choose, which data it wants to use: the ones from "object" or the ones from "embed".

Firefox, Safari, Opera, etc. seem to prefer the embed variant, while IE prefers the object variant.

I would suggest to remove the "embed" variant and only use the "object" variant. That is the correct variant according to the HTML 4 standard. The embed variant is only supported by browsers for compatibility reasons.